# Limit Output File Size during uploading of file

Tags: database, file, output, size, limit

We have a tool that uploads a script in the Database server and returns the output to the user. We save the output file in the server for the user to be able to download it. However, we want to limit the size of the file being saved in the server.

Is there a way to limit the output file size during the execution so that it will stop the execution when the limit has been reached?

Comment: Which database, do you have some code you can share?

Comment: `logFilePath = new StringBuilder().Append(workingDir).Append("/").Append(logFileName).ToString();
                    if (File.Exists(logFilePath) && (new FileInfo(logFilePath).Length >= Conf.MaximumOutputFileSize))
                    {               
                        p.Kill();
                        return p;
                    }`

Comment: It kills the execution however, the output file size exceeds that of the set MaximumOutputFileSize.

Comment: Are you using SQL, Access, mySQL database and the language, is that Java, C# etc?

Comment: SQL Database and MVC :)